# Differences between "conditions that start with for all" VS "conditions that end with for all."

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I always have trouble with interpreting the differences between them, so I would like to get help interpreting the differences between the following two statements (that are numbered.)

Let, $T \in L(V)$ where $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space.

And, let $T$ be fixed.

And, suppose that we have a subspace of $L(V)$ "$X$" s.t $X = \{ Y \in L(V) : YT=TY \}$.

1. For every $Y \in X$, we have $YT=TY$. (This is very clear to me.)
2. $YT=TY$ for any $Y \in X$. (This is somewhat doubtful to say it is identical to 1.)

Are these identical statements since $T$ is fixed in this case?

Also, any pro-tips for interpreting differences between "conditions that start with for all" and "conditions that end with for all" in general cases are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are identical. The first one is more proper in the sense that the order of the english words matches the order of the logical quantifiers $\forall Y \in X, YT = TY$. The second one has the english for all at the end. This is common, and sometimes it reads more naturally for me.

Comment: Thank you! Is it because $T$ is fixed?

Comment: Well, if $T$ wasn't fixed, then $T$ is undefined and neither statement would make any sense.

Comment: You're right. Actually, what I meant was "if we are looking for a $T$." Assume that $T$ isn't fixed. And, let's assume that we have 1. For every $Y \in X, YT = TY$. Find $T$ with this condition. 2. Look for $T$ s.t $YT=TY$ for any $Y \in X$. In this case, 1. and 2. means different? Am I right?

Comment: @john I don't understand what you just wrote. 1 and 2 mean the same thing regardless of what $X$ and $T$ are.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212660/prove-there-exists-a-positive-number-c-such-that-v-1%e2%89%a4c-v-2-for-all-v%e2%88%88v

Comment: In the link above, I have misinterpreted the given condition as a comment in there says. So, I was wondering what is a major difference between two.

Comment: Well, this might not be strictly related to this post, but hope you could see the reason I posted this question. Anyways, it was a big help!